# I've kept a class and its members from Proguards obfuscation, but a static final member is obfuscated?

Tags: android, proguard

I have this class

```
public class MyClass extends StringType implements ProtectedAgainstProguard {

    private static final String delimiter = "#";
    private static final MyClass singleton = new MyClass ();

    private MyClass() {
        super(someStuff);
    }

    public static MyClass getSingleton() {
        return singleton;
    }

    @Override
    public Object someMethodA() {

    }

    @Override
    public Object someMethodB() {

    }
}
```

Here's my ProGuard config:

```
-keep public interface com.example.android.application.ProtectedAgainstProguard
-keep public class * implements com.example.android.application.ProtectedAgainstProguard
-keep class * implements com.example.android.application.ProtectedAgainstProguard
-keep public class * extends com.example.android.application.ProtectedAgainstProguard
-keep class * extends com.example.android.application.ProtectedAgainstProguard
```

and here is the mapping.txt for this class

```
com.example.android.domain.MyClass -> com.example.android.domain.MyClass :
    com.example.android.domain.MyClass singleton -> a
    15:16:void <init>() -> <init>
    24:28:java.lang.Object someMethodA() -> someMethodA
    34:38:java.lang.Object someMethodB() -> someMethodB
    12:12:void <clinit>() -> <clinit>
```

As you can see the `static final` singleton (dont know if its the member or the method, I think its the method, is obfuscated.
How do I tell proguard to just keep its hands off the entire class and everything in it?
I don't want to list particular classes and their particular methods/members that I want to keep, I just want a general rule that says "don't do ANYTHING to a class that implements `ProtectedAgainstProguard` "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:--

```
-keep interface com.example.android.application.ProtectedAgainstProguard {*;}
-keepclasseswithmembers class * implements com.example.android.application.ProtectedAgainstProguard{*;}
-keepclasseswithmembers interface * extends com.example.android.application.ProtectedAgainstProguard{*;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out in order to protect the members of the class, we need to add `{ *; }` at the end of the rule - because `keep` isn't very useful by itself.

```
-keep public interface com.example.android.application.ProtectedAgainstProguard { *; }
-keep public class * implements com.example.android.application.ProtectedAgainstProguard { *; }
-keep class * implements com.example.android.application.ProtectedAgainstProguard { *; }
-keep public class * extends com.example.android.application.ProtectedAgainstProguard { *; }
-keep class * extends com.example.android.application.ProtectedAgainstProguard { *; }
```